# Loads of SQL calls in MiniProfiler when using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using [miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) and noticed that immediately after a rebuild it's giving me a crazy number of sql calls (485).

[image]

But the next time I call the page it seems to be caching / re-reading the result, because the call times are minimal. However the sql calls have reduced to a reasonable number (3). Also this seems to be a new occurance but I can't pinpoint when it started exactly.

Therefore I'm confused as to whether or not I have a problem. Does anybody know if this pertains to the rebuild and can I safely ignore it?

Or is it something I should investigate further?

[image]

Comment: What is "a crazy number"? I think this is just EF checking the database structure against the model hash it has stored in the migration table (maybe 10-15 queries). This only happens when an application is started and a context is used for the first time.

Comment: Thanks Gert. 485 is the crazy number.  There's about 20 tables, one of which stores 10 or so derived classes (table per hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MiniProfiler is recording all of the db calls made when you are attempting to drop and recreate the database.

If you don't want to record these and still want to profile that request, then try using the `Ignore` command in MiniProfiler.

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Ignore()) 
{
  DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(
                            new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
  DbDatabase.Initialize(false);
}
```

Include the [`Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) function call within the `Ignore` block in order to make sure that initialization happens when you want it to happen.

Comment: Thanks Yaakov, I don't know who downvoted the answer, I didn't know how to do that and think it's pretty helpful :)

Comment: The initializer is only set here. It will start doing stuff when a context is initialized, so it is useless to turn off MiniProfiler here.

Comment: @GertArnold good call. I added `Initialize` within the ignored section of code to address this.